# Can you enable the meta key in Mavericks?

Tags: macos

According to several help posts ([for example](http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/01/30/alt-key-aan-de-praat-in-osx-terminal/)), you used to be able to enable the option/alt key to act as a meta key. Can you no longer do that in Mavericks?

Comment: What do you mean by a meta key? any info should be in the question and not just a link which could break in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still possible in Mavericks. Have you looked under Terminal `Preferences > Settings Tab > Profiles > Default Profile > Keyboard` and then ticked "Use option as meta key" at the bottom?

[image: Option as Meta]

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I was looking under System Preferences, not Terminal Preferences. Thanks for your help, and apologies for the silly question.

Comment: Glad to help. It does seem kind of weird that it is a profile setting rather than a system-wide one.